# Translated property parameter in Angular5

Tags: html, angular, internationalization, primeng

I have [primeNg multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect)  (this is pure example from site, without anything added).

on my module I import:

```
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/multiselect';
```

than I create component with *.html as:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1">
</p-multiSelect>
```

and *.ts:

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

interface City {
    name: string,
    code: string
}

export class MyModel {
    cities1: SelectItem[];
    selectedCities1: City[];

    constructor() {
        this.cities1 = [
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];
    }
}
```

There are built-in properties like `[defaultLabel]="choose"` which are strings.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
               [defaultLabel]="choose"
</p-multiSelect>
```

Now I would've like to change default label depending on i18n:

Normally in html I use i18n as:

```
<p>{{'MULTISELECT.DEFAULT' | translate }}</p>
```

But it's not gonna work as:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
               [defaultLabel]="{{'MULTISELECT.DEFAULT' | translate }}"
</p-multiSelect>
```

Any ideas how to pass translate value to the property parameter?

Comment: Can't you fill that `defaultLabel` from the component after having translated it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive that we can use `translateService: TranslateService`. Imported by `import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`

We can use it as:

```
this.translateService.get("MULTISELECT.DEFAULT").subscribe((translatedLabel: string) => {
      this.translatedMultiSelectDefaultLabel= translatedLabel;
    });
```

and than just assign as:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
               [defaultLabel]="translatedMultiSelectDefaultLabel"
</p-multiSelect>
```